# In/on the middle of the stairs

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

I know that for stairs, the preposition 'on' is much more correct and suitable than 'in'. However, if I try to form a sentence like the one below:

- He suddenly stopped dead ON/IN the middle of the stairs.

Which one should I use? Although 'ON' would be the logical choice, 'IN' sounds much more pleasing to the ear in that phrase. Google Ngram supports that:
[image]

Comment: I think you can answer your own question. "In the middle" is far more common in all contexts than "on the middle" the evidence is ngrams

Comment: Yes but I can find quite a few solid examples of 'on the middle of the stairs' and even 'at the middle of the stairs' on google book search. Which is why I want to see  the views of other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual expression is

> **in** the middle of the stairs

since "the stairs" is a location with a beginning (bottom) and an end (top, depending on perspective).  You might also use

> **on** the middle stair

which is the stair step equidistant from the top and bottom, and equivalent to

> **at** the middle of the stairs

Comment: I thought about this question for a bit, and eventually came to pretty much the same conclusion you did. While I don't think _on_ would be "wrong," I think the three alternatives you mention here seem more common and natural.